# How to specify the "latest" version in Semver?

Tags: python-poetry, semantic-versioning

To date, I have been able to declare some packages as "latest" in my `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.9.*"
Authlib = "latest"
requests = "latest"
```

All is fine, until I upgrade to Poetry v1.2, whence it becomes not fine...

```
  ParseConstraintError

  Could not parse version constraint: latest

  at ~/.asdf/installs/poetry/1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/core/constraints/version/parser.py:147 in parse_single_constraint
      143│         return version
      144│ 
      145│     from poetry.core.constraints.version.exceptions import ParseConstraintError
      146│ 
    → 147│     raise ParseConstraintError(f"Could not parse version constraint: {constraint}")
```

Looking through [PEP440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/) and [Semver](https://semver.org/) I can find no reference to indicate "latest" is actually a valid thing.

So, two questions:

1. Why does "latest" work in Poetry<1.2 but not >=1.2, or have I got this wrong?
2. Is there a semver symbol for "latest"?  If so, what?

thx

Answer (score 0):

"latest" has worked in Poetry < 1.2, because Poetry silently assume `*` for any invalid version constraint. Since 1.2 it throws an exception instead.

If you don't want to give any restriction to the version use `*`, which  mean "any suitable version". If it's possible most dependency resolver like Poetry or pip will choose the latest version available then.